# Соответствует ли решение заданию?Создайте объект класса View, удовлетворяющий следующим требованиям:

Tags: php

## Задание:

1. Создайте объект класса View, удовлетворяющий следующим требованиям:
2. Конструктор не имеет аргументов (а может быть вообще не нужен никакой конструктор)
3. Есть метод assign($name, $value), чья задача - сохранить данные, передаваемые в шаблон по заданному имени (используйте защищенное свойство - массив для хранения этих данных)
4. Есть метод display($template), который отображает указанный шаблон с заранее сохраненными данными
5. Метод render($template), который аналогичен методу display(), но не выводит шаблон с данными в браузер, а возвращает его

## Решение:

```
Файл: index.php

<?php

require __DIR__ . '/src/View.php';
$view = new View;
$view->assing('title', 'Главная страница');
$view->assing('h1', 'Привет!');
$view->assing('p', 'МИР');
$view->render(__DIR__ . '/templates/index.php');
//$view->display(__DIR__ . '/templates/index.php');

Файл: /templates/index.php


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title><?php echo $this->data['title']; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1><?php echo $this->data['h1']?></h1>
    <p><?php echo $this->data['p']?></p>
</body>
</html>

Файл: /src/View.php

<?php

class View
{
    protected $data = [];

    public function assing($name, $value){
         $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function display(string $template){
        echo require $template;
    }

    public function render(string $template){
        ob_start();
        require  $template;
        return ob_end_flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: шаблон обычно находится в отдельном файле, и передавать в display/render тербуется имя файла шаблона, а не генерацию непонятно чего. `assign` в свою очередь может вызываться не единожды, а для передачи в шаблон разных переменных.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Переделал, так должно быть больше похоже на правду. Меня очень смущает момент в шаблоне, правильно ли организован вывод данных с массива?

Comment: методы display и render идентичны и по сути не делают ничего, вы передаете аргумент в метод и он сразу этот аргумент возвращает, какой смысл от этих методов?

Comment: метод assign не должен выводить данные а только записывать. foreach кстати вам совсем не нужен, в метод display нужно передать название шаблон и он в свою очередь должен вернуть сам шаблон, для этого и нужен был метод assign, чтобы передать туда нужное количество шаблонов, и отображать по имени

Comment: По идее задача метода display вывести  в  поток вывода шаблон с данными, которые лежат в свойстве. А render вернуть этот шаблон с этими же данными.

Comment: только при этом он должен сам найти этот шаблон где-то и подставить туда данные из `$this->data` а не то, что у вас тут  напиано.

Comment: В смысле "сам найти"? Я не должен в качетсве аргумента указывать полный путь к шаблону?

Comment: @DenysSkotarenko это надо делать в assign

Comment: Хорошо. Получается, что 1. в assing передается два аргумента 2. через $this я указываю путь к шаблону, так? Если да, то что тогда нужно в передавать в display в качестве аргумента $template?

Comment: @DenysSkotarenko в методе assign есть два аргумента name и value, в name задаете вымышленное название шаблона (называйте как хотите), затем в value пишите путь к своему шаблону. В display в аргумент передаете ваше вымышленное имя по которому он отображает шаблон $this->data[$template].

Comment: @Alpha переосмыслил и переделал. Так должно получиться было изначально?

Comment: @Alpha `assign` он для передачи переменных в шаблон, а не для назначения шаблона и пути к нему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php

include $view->display('template');
```

Инклюд здесь явно не нужен. Должно быть просто `$view->display('template');`

Метод `assign()` должен назначать переменной шаблона какое-то значение. Например, если сделать `$view->assign('title', 'Главная');` должен назначить заголовок страницы `Главная`

Метод `render()` в целом правильно, но в него нужно передавать полный путь файла.

Метод `display()` по идее должен выглядеть как-то так:

```php
<?php
class View
{
    // ...

    public function display($template)
    {
        echo $this->render($template);
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Переделал и осознал, что и куда нужно передавать. Еще раз спасибо!